# How do I parametrize a URL for POST using Swagger?

Tags: rest, swagger, swagger-ui

I would like to define the following path using [Swagger](http://swagger.io/):

```
/api/libraries/1234/books
```

And `POST` a book to the books collection of library, whose id is `1234`.

In the example, I've seen here: https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-spec/blob/master/examples/v2.0/json/petstore-with-external-docs.json

It shows like, you can specify for example: `libraries/{id}/books`, but you have to define it as a separate path object.

For example, comparing with `libraries`, for `GET` purposes; which will retrieve you a list of libraries.

Is there a way to define a `sub path` object (for example: under 
`libraries` define a `sub path` of `id`), and under it a `sub path` of `books`; and maybe another `sub path` of `employees`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The short answer is no.

Nesting paths is not supported according to the swagger spec 2.0; you have to define paths independently (https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-spec/blob/master/versions/2.0.md#pathItemObject).

You can then group a list of resources using ***tags***.

Reason for having atomic paths lies with swaggers strong compliance with the REST specs. In REST resources are linked to independent atomic operations (unlike SOAP/RPC).

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if I understand your question correctly but if you want to define path variables for `/api/libraries/1234/books/5678/employees/9999` as an example, the path should look like this:

```
/api/libraries/{library_id}/books/{book_id}/employees/{employe_id}
```

in which `{library_id}`, `{book_id}` and `{employee_id}` are path variables.