# Modelling a hierarchy in Swagger / OpenAPI Spec

Tags: json, api, swagger

I have an existing JSON based api, which uses a hierarchy to provide access to a hierarchy based model of data.

The api works kinda like this:

**/**

List all bases

**/{some_base}**

List everything in this level of hierarchy + additional properties of some_base

**/{some_base}/{some_child}**

List everything in the next level of hierarchy + additional properties of some_child

**/{some_base}/{some_child}/some_action**

Execute an action for the selected path.

Is there a way to model such a hierarchy in Swagger/OpenAPI spec or do I have to break everything up into

**/bases/**

**/bases/{some_base}**

**/children/of?{some_base}**
etc?

Comment: Could you provide some examples of what data you get on each level?

Comment: I guess that kind of hierarchy should be specified independently -yeah, you'd better break those up:
http://stackoverflow.com/a/31512253